# Python -- list into dict

Tags: python, dictionary, twitter

I'm very new to programming (taking my first class in it now), so bear with me for format issues and misunderstandings, or missing easy fixes.

I have a dict with tweet data: 'user' as keys and then 'text' as their values. My goal here is to find the tweets where they are replying to another user, signified by starting with the @ symbol, and then make a new dict that contains the author's user and the users of everyone he replied to. That's the fairly simple if statement I have below. I was also able to use the split function to isolate the username of the person they are replying to (the function takes all the text between the @ symbol and the next space after it).

```
st='@'
en=' '
tweets1={}
for t in a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n:
    if t['text'][0]=='@':
         print(t['user']),print(t['text'].split(st)[-1].split(en)[0])
         tweets1(user,repliedto)=(t['user'],t['text'].split(st)[-1].split(en)[0])
```

```
st='@'
en=' '
task1dict={}
for t in a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n:
    if t['text'][0]=='@':
        user=t['user']
        repliedto=t['text'].split(st)[-1].split(en)[0]
        task1dict[user]=[repliedto]
```

Username1 replied to username2. Username2 replied to both username3 and username5.

I am trying to create a dict (caled tweets1) that reads something like:

```
'user':'repliedto'
username1:[username2]
username2:[username3, username5]
```

etc.

The problem I have been running into is with the line:

```
tweets1(user,repliedto)=(t['user'],t['text'].split(st)[-1].split(en)[0])
```

I am getting the error code "SyntaxError: can't assign to function call".
I have tried different variations of code trying to achieve the same result and have not found a way that works, probably because of the use of the split function.

Is there a better way to isolate the usernames, and then put them into a new dict? Here's a 2 entry sample of the tweet data:

```
{"user":"datageek88","text":"@sundevil1992 good question! @joeclarknet Is this on the exam?"},
{"user":"joeclarkphd","text":"Exam questions will be answered in due time @sundevil1992"}
```

I am now able to add them to a dict, but it would only save one 'repliedto' for each 'user', so instead of showing username2 have replied to both 3 and 5, it just shows the latest one, 5:

```
{'username1': ['username2'],
'username2': ['username5']}
```

Again, if I'm making a serious no-no anywhere in here, I apologize, and please show me what I'm doing wrong!

Thanks.

Comment: I made a change to the code and the post, and edited with my new problem.

Comment: Please start a new question rather than making wholesale changes to the original.

Comment: Please, could you rollback to the original question, accept the best answer and create a new question for the second problem?

Answer (score 1):

You are using parentheses where you should be using square brackets:

```
tweets1[user,repliedto] = (t['user'],t['text'].split(st)[-1].split(en)[0])
```

Comment: Thanks! I made some changes, would you be able to read the post again and see if you can help with my new issue?

Answer (score 0):

This line has the form of a function call:

```
tweets1(user,repliedto)=...
```

and you can't assign to that.

`tweets1` is a dictionary and you should be using square brackets `[]`